# Tagging a question that interests you as a favourite on the Mobile App

Tags: feature-request

I use the Android Mobile Stack Exchange application. It happens that I have a couple of questions that really interest me, but I can't keep track of them if I haven't given a response to them.

Maybe on the website there is a way of tagging questions as favourites to keep track of them; if there is, I wish in the future that an option like that could be added to the mobile app as well.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to _mark_ questions as favorite on the app, or a way to _find_ your favorites? This needs clarified a bit. (As a side note for when you edit to clarify this, the word "I" should always be capitalized. ("i" > "I") I would fix this, but I don't have edit privileges.)

Comment: To mark them as favourites so that i can revisit them easily: just edited my question thank you @Kendra

Comment: There's already a way to mark them. Along the bottom of the question, between the text of the post and the user card, you should see "Favorite Share More" and their icons. Now, once you _tag_ it on the app, there isn't currently a way to get to your favorites list (that I can find) but you will be able to find them on your profile on the desktop/mobile web. (The profile on the mobile app really leaves something to be desired.) I'd answer with a screenshot to help you out, but unfortunately I'm currently unable to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can already mark questions as favorite in the Android app *and* find them as well. Finding them isn't *obvious,* but it can be done.

To mark a question as a favorite, find the "Favorite" link under the question text. You should see "Favorite Shared More" and their icons there, above and to the right of the user card.

If you want to *find* your favorites through the app, go to the site you want to search and type in the search bar "infavorites:mine" and you'll get the list of your favorites. As a bonus, you can further search your favorites this way by adding another search parameter. For example, "infavorites:mine java" or "infavorites:mine unicorns".